# customized uitableview with chat bubbles

Tags: iphone, uitableview, sms, chat

I'm building a SMS like app, with chat bubbles. To do that I'm using a customized uitableview which gets data from an array and puts cells with pair indexPath on the right and with odd indexPath on the left

Everything works fine, but the only problem is that there can't be 2 cells one above the other in the same same position (left or right) and I need this as maybe a user can send 2 or more messages while the other one didn't send anything

I'm thinking in a way of doing that but nothing comes up to my mind so do you suggest a way ?

Comment: Maybe grow the bubble when the user adds a message?

Comment: That's a good one, I'll give it a try, thanks mate !

Answer (score 2):

You can't assume that the two users will alternate messages back and forth, so the even/odd check will have to be thrown out.

You mention you store the messages in an array.  Perhaps create another array of the same size, and when you add a message to the first array, you can add something to the second array that lets you know which user it is from.  Then, when you create your cells, you can determine if it should be on the left or right using the second array, and fill the content of the bubble from the message array.

Answer (score 0):

Could you just check if the message originated from the device I'm holding and put it on the left side?

If the data you are pulling from somehow identifies the user, you could easily check which user sent the message and position the cell based on that.